# Custom Export Report issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, csv, export

I need to export the custom grid to the csv file. I have used the below code in my listing.xml file.

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">catalogreport/export/gridToCsv</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">catalogreport/export/gridToXml</item>
                    </item> 
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
```

Then in my

> **Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/gridToCsv.php**

```
class GridToCsv extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
      $fileName = "CustomSales_". date('Ymd_His').".csv";
      $dataSource = //The data fetches here;
      $handle = fopen($fileName, 'w');
      // Adding my logic to write the content to the file
      $this->downloadCsv($fileName);

    }


    public function downloadCsv($fileName)
    {
        if (file_exists($fileName)) {
             //set appropriate headers
             header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
             header('Content-Type: application/csv');
             header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fileName));
             header('Expires: 0');
             header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
             header('Pragma: public');
             header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
             ob_clean();flush();
             readfile($fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine, The file is downloading successfully, But here my question is the CSV file is storing into the root directory, I need to change to `pub/media/import` directory.

How this can be done here? I want to store the csv file inside `pub/media/import` directory.

Can anyone suggest me please. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `Content-Disposition` in function `downloadCsv($fileName)`to

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$directory.'/'.$fileName);
```

Where $directory will be the media folder path which you can get dynamically by adding dependency in constructor using below code

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $_filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
)
{
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
}
```

```
$mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
$directory = mediapath.'import'
```